# Impersonation In Crystal Reports

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, crystal-reports, impersonation

I've been trying to update a WCF project that interacts with Crystal Reports to get it to connect to a MS SQL Server via Windows Authentication.
It is a WCF project but is running as a Windows Service and not through IIS.

I am using [SimpleImpersonation](https://github.com/mj1856/SimpleImpersonation) to do the impersonation step.
Essentially, if the correct values are provided in the incoming SOAP request, including IntegratedSecurity=true, it impersonates another user and tries to log in with IntegratedSecurity.

My code looks something like this:

```
using (Impersonation.LogonUser(domain, username, password, LogonType.NewCredentials)) {
    reportDocument.Execute();
}
```

I know impersonation is working because I've printed `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` before and after the `using` statement and saw the username change to what I want after the `using`.

I have tried each of the different `LogonType`s but I get the same results.

I get a `Database logon failed` error message from calling `Execute()`.
**However, if I start the web service running as the account I'm trying to impersonate, I am able to connect to the database properly.**

My questions are:

- Is Impersonation working the way I'm intending it to? Am I doing something wrong? (It doesn't look like it based off of the documentation)
- Is there something with the Crystal Reports runtime for .NET that I need to configure differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my issue was not with impersonation, but with a DB driver. I found a comment on https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3621859:

> Please check the  file "sqlncli.dll" exist in server or not?  .. not sure this file or some other dll.

I installed https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=50402 on the server and my code started working automagically.

I wish the error messages returned from Crystal Reports were a bit more descriptive, but oh well, at least it's working.